# changes to header.php not appearing

Tags: plugins

I have taken on a new wp site which needs some tlc. It has a pile of plugins I haven't used - one of which is 'WP File manager'

I made a simple change to the header.php - just to make sure i was in the right place. Change appeared on the site. Then I deleted the change, saved the file again and now - - - it is still appearing (on some browsers - I got a friend who has never visited before and my alteration is still there). I have reopened the header file and code shows that my alteration has been removed)

Can anyone suggest what is going on and how to get my alterations to the code to be reliably reflected.

(BTW I have asked for ftp access)

Thanks

Edward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may some caching on the Site. There may be different types of caches. make sure to check  & flush them all.

1. Clearing the Browser Cache
2. Server-side Caching
3. A WordPress Cache Plugin.

If nothing happens try following.

1. Make a backup of the file you are working on and check that the backup is in a safe place.
2. Make a big change (such as setting the background in your style.css as #ff0000 or even red).
3. View the changed web page in your browser. Make sure you clear the cache, to be sure you have the new version.
4. If nothing changes, delete the file (and only that file) from the server and try to view the file again. If nothing continues to change, you and WordPress are looking at completely different files. It's time to get out your detective hat and start figuring out what is happening and where your files went.
5. Check your URL settings in your options panel and also in the database. If this issue still continues to be unsolvable, make a post about it on the WordPress Forum, and let the experts step in to help.

**Further more avoid working using such File Manager & File editor plugins.**

Comment: Thanks for your long and helpful reply! I have carried out much of what you suggested - and then discovered that in fact a cache plugin was installed. Having deactivated this i can now see my changes - but not always. I would like to remove the whole thing, just have to persuade the client that its a good idea. As far as I can see the cache plugin has been used as an excuse to let bad practice through!